# Data usage limit of the Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking

I would like to put a data usage limit of my Wi-Fi.

Is there a way to do this?

Is there a way(for example a computer program) to receive a notification when I reach the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bandwidth-limit in any router works in the same way:

Primary Steps:

- Login to your Router.
- Collect IP from active client table.
- Go to Bandwidth Settings.
- Input value: IP, Bandwidth limit.
- Save Settings.

Now, each router has a different set of settings and different names for that. If you can't find it yourself in the settings, try searching for a manual on the specific model, or asking the technical team of brand of your router